# Maven and M2Eclipse Co-existing

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Firstly I've installed `maven 3` to /path/to/maven and configured /path/to/maven/conf/setting.xml below,

```
<localRepository>/path/to/repository</localRepository>
```

then installed `m2eclipse` on Eclipse 3.7.2 for Java EE and configured it below,

```
preferences->maven->
 installation->"/path/to/maven"
 userSettings->"/path/to/maven/conf/setting.xml"
 localRepository->"/path/to/repository"
```

On completion of building the index by `m2eclipse`, a duplicate `.cache` directory has been generated under both /path/to/repository and /path/to/home/.m2/repository below,

```
.cache/
└── [4.0K]  m2e
    └── [4.0K]  1.2.0
        └── ....
            ├── [ 64M]  nexus-maven-repository-index.gz
            └── [1.1K]  nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
```

- What could have caused the index duplication? Is it just normal?
- What would be the side effects on the index above, if I use both `mvn CLI` and `m2eclispe` alternately (not in parallel)?

Answer (score 2):

It is not common to have two repositories.  Both m2e and cli should point to same repo. Verify your eclipse settings for maven.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin is right - you're probably misconfigured.  That said, I would consider dropping a symlink in my home directory instead of configuring a different path.  That way there is no need to ensure that any tool is configured correctly, as the default location just points somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Having duplicate repositories could be caused by bad formed settings.xml. e.g. if it contains errors (like some unclosed tags), m2eclipse will ignore it and generate a new in-memory settings model, using the default values.

In command line, check that `mvn help:effective-settings` executes properly.

The cached index is only used by m2e, so it can't be corrupted when using both m2e and maven CLI.